# parse mathematical expression in c

Tags: c, expression, calculator, realloc, evaluation

I am Writing a simple calculator that accepts arguments from command line and evaluates the string.
Intentionally, it should accept the mathematical expression and evaluate it but it throws some errors while running it. However it gets compiled successfully.

It throws following errors:-

> Segmentation fault

> free(): double free detected in tcache 2
> Aborted

> realloc(): invalid next size
> Aborted

Here is my calc.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<math.h>
#include"replace.h"


#define EXPL 200 //expression lenght
#define MAXLEN 512
#define HAFLEN 256

void DisplayHelp(void);
int validate(char*);
int issign(char);
char* evaluate(char*);
long double calculate(char*);
long double getNext(char*);
long double getPrev(char*, char*);
int calcValidate(char*);
void operate(char*, char);
int issign(char);
long double strtonum(char*);


void DisplayHelp(){
    char str[] = "calc <expression>\n"\
    "expression: it is the mathematical expression that is to be calculated or evaluated.\n"\
    "You can also use just 'calc' without any argument to start a calculator program.\n";
    printf("%s\n",str);
}

int issign(char s)
{
    char signs[8] = "-+/*^";
    if(strchr(signs, s))
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
int validate(char *src)
{
    char *init = src;
    //check if all the characters are acceptable
    while (*src){
        if( 
            isdigit(*src)
            || *src == '(' || *src == ')' 
        || *src == '.' || *src == '+' 
        || *src == '-' || *src == '^'
        || *src == '/' || *src == '*' 
        )
            src++;
            else{
                puts(init);
                printf("Expression Contains Illegal Character at position %d.\n", (int)(src - init) + 1);
                return 0;
            }
    }
    
    //check if there is brace after operator
    src = init;
    if(strstr(src, "-)") || strstr(src, "+)") 
        || strstr(src, "/)") || strstr(src, "*)")
        || strstr(src, "^)")){
            printf("Expected a number after after operator. Got brace ')'\n");
            return 0;
        }
        
        //check missing brackets
        int hasBrace = 0;
    if(strchr(src, '('))
        hasBrace = 1;
    
    src = init;
    int brace = 0;
    while(*src){
        if(*src == '(')
            ++brace;
        else if(*src == ')')
            brace -= 1;
        ++src;
    }
    if(brace){
        printf("%d Missing braces\n", brace);
        return 0;
    }
    
    //check for missing operator after or before  braces and add multiply operator in between
    if(hasBrace){
        //first count how many * should be inserted and store the index
        src = init;
        int insCount = 0;
        int index[(int)strlen(src)];
        // printf("%ld size of array, %ld\n", sizeof(index)/sizeof(int), strlen(init));
        while(*src){
            if(*src == '(' || *src == ')'){
                if(*src == '('){
                    if(src != init) --src;
                   if(isdigit(*src)){
                       index[insCount] = (int)(src  - init) + 1; // index of (
                           ++insCount;
                   }
                   ++src;
                }
                else if(*src == ')'){
                           ++src;
                           if(isdigit(*src) || *src == '('){
                               index[insCount] = (int)(src - init);
                               ++insCount;
                           }
                           --src;
                }
            }
            ++src;
        }
        //now insert * in the indexed position
        src = init;
        char  *tmp = (char*)malloc(((int)strlen(src) + insCount + 1) * (int)sizeof(char)); //+1 for \0
        if(tmp == NULL)
            exit(-1);
        strcpy(tmp, src);
        //store how many * added as it will change the other stored index in the array
        int added = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < insCount; ++i){
            char *ret = insert(tmp, "*", index[i] + added);
            strcpy(tmp, ret);
            ++added;
            free(ret); 
        }
        src = realloc(src, strlen(tmp)  + 1);
        strcpy(src, tmp);
        free(tmp);
    }
    
    //check for empty braces
    src = init;
    if(hasBrace){
        while(*src){
            if(*src == '('){
                ++src;
                if(*src == ')'){
                printf("Empty braces.\n");
                return 0;
                }
                --src;
            }
            src++;
        }
    }
    
    //check if expression contains operators in invalid place
    if(!calcValidate(init)){
        puts("Got unexpected operator(s) at unexpected place");
        return 0;
    }
    
    
    return 1;
}

char* evaluate(char *exp)
{
    //since we will insert every result of evaluation in the exp, it may contain exp and resutl or brac exp like 3^4^3 so very long
    exp = realloc(exp, MAXLEN);
    if(!exp)
        exit(-1);
    char *init = exp;
    long expl = strlen(exp);
    
    //count total open brackets
    int brace = 0;
    while(*exp){
        if(*exp == '(')
            ++brace;
        ++exp;
    }
    exp = init;
    int isWholeInsideBrace = 0;
    if(*exp == '(')
        isWholeInsideBrace = 1;
    
    if(brace){
        for(int i = brace; i > 0; --i){
            int bracth = 0; //nth brace e.g. 4th brace
            char bracexp[MAXLEN] = "";
            char curAns[MAXLEN] = ""; //store current ans, later replace bracexp in exp with it
            char *bracclos = "";
            while(*exp){
                if(*exp == '('){
                    ++bracth;
                    if(bracth != i){
                        ++exp;
                        continue;
                    }
                    bracclos = strchr(exp, ')');
                strncpy(bracexp, exp, bracclos - exp + 1); //copy from '(' to ')'
    snprintf(curAns, MAXLEN, "%.256Lg", calculate(bracexp));
    char *replExp = replace(init, bracexp, curAns, 1);
    strcpy(init, replExp);
    free(replExp);
    // exit(0);
    break;
    
                }
                ++exp;
            }
            exp = init;
        }
    } 
    if(!isWholeInsideBrace){
        snprintf(exp, MAXLEN, "%.256Lg", calculate(exp));
    }
    return exp;
}

long double calculate(char* expre)
{
    char tmp[MAXLEN] = "";
    long double ans = 0.0;
    char* ptr = tmp;
    
    //remove brace from if exist
    while(*expre){
        if(*expre != '(' && *expre != ')'){
            *ptr = *expre;
            ++ptr;
        }
        ++expre;
    }
    *ptr = '\0';
    ptr = tmp;
    
    if(strchr(tmp, '^'))
        operate(tmp, '^');
    
    if(strchr(tmp, '/'))
        operate(tmp, '/');
    
    if(strchr(tmp, '*'))
        operate(tmp, '*');
    
    // for + and - need to check if there is only one number, else infinite loop        
    if(strchr(tmp, '+') )
        operate(tmp, '+');
    
    if(strchr(tmp, '-') )
        operate(tmp, '-');
    
    //if the exp does not contain any signs means it if already calculated or it is single number
    return atof(tmp);
}

void operate(char *temp, char sign)
{
    long double num1 = 0;
    long double num2 = 0;
    char curExp[MAXLEN] = "";
    char curAns[MAXLEN] = "";
    char *replaced;
    char *oper;
    
    long double ans = 0;
    while((oper = strchr(temp,sign))){
        num1 = getPrev(temp, oper);
        num2 = getNext(oper);
        
        if(sign == '^')
            ans = pow(num1, num2);
        else if(sign == '/')
            ans = num1 / num2;
        else if(sign == '*')
            ans = num1 * num2;
        else if(sign == '+')
            ans = num1 + num2;
        else if(sign == '-')
            ans = num1 - num2;
        
        //if first letter is + or - , getPrev returns 0 so ignore it
        //check and specify the format
        char secfor[15] = "";
        char ansfor[10] = "";
        
        if(oper == temp && !isdigit(*oper))
            snprintf(curExp, MAXLEN,((int)num2 == num2)? "%c%.0Lf" : "%c%.4Lf", *oper, num2);
        else{
            int a,b;
            a = (int)num1;
            b = (int)num2;
            if(a == num1 && b ==  num2)
                strcpy(secfor, "%.0Lf%c%.0Lf");
            else if(a == num1)
                strcpy(secfor, "%.0Lf%c%.4Lf");
            else if(b == num2)
                strcpy(secfor, "%.4Lf%c%.0Lf");
            else
                strcpy(secfor, "%.4Lf%c%.4Lf");
            
            snprintf(curExp, MAXLEN, secfor, num1, *oper, num2);
        }
        
        snprintf(curAns, MAXLEN,((int)ans == ans)? "%.0Lf" : "%.4Lf", ans);
        replaced = replace(temp, curExp, curAns, 1);
        // printf("%s\n%s\t%s\n%s\n", temp, curExp, curAns, replaced);
        strcpy(temp, replaced);
        printf("new temp: %s\n\n", temp);
        
        free(replaced);
        //special cases:-
        //if first letter is + or - and there is only one number, so break the loop
        if(sign == '+' || sign == '-'){
            char *ptr = temp;
            if(sign == '+'){
                if(strrchr(temp, '+') == ptr && !strchr(temp, '-'))
                    break;
            }
            else if(sign == '-'){
                if(strrchr(temp, '-') == ptr)
                    break;
            }
        }    
    }
}

int calcValidate(char *val)
{
    char *point = val;
    char first = *point;
    //take pointer to end of string
    point = strchr(point, '\0');
    --point;
    char last = *point;
    point = val;
    
    if(!isdigit(first) && (first != '-' || first != '+'))
        return 0;
    else if(!isdigit(last) && last != '(' && last != ')')
        return 0;
    
    //check whether operators are doubled
    int doubled = 0;
    while(*point){
        if(isdigit(*point) || *point == '(' || *point == ')')
            doubled = 0;
        else if(issign(*point)){
            if(doubled)
                return 0;
            doubled = 1;
        }
        ++point;
    }
    return 1;
}

long double getNext(char* pos)
{
    char *tmp = pos;
    //pos is the position of operator, ignore it, and return numbers from it to next operator
    ++tmp;
    return strtonum(tmp);
}

long double getPrev(char* str, char* pos)
{
    char *tmp = str;
    char *tmpp = pos;
    //if + or - is at first, return 0
    if(tmpp == str)
        return 0;
    --tmpp;
    while(tmpp != str  && isdigit(*tmpp))
        --tmpp;
    //tmpp now is the position of operator , so get number between this operator to another operator i.e. pos
    if(tmpp != str)
        ++tmpp;
    return strtonum(tmpp);
}

long double strtonum(char* s)
{
    char *ptr = s;
    char sign = '\0';
    long double beforeDecimal = 0.0;
    float afterDecimal = 0.0;
    
    float a, c = 10;
    int exp = 1;
    if(*ptr == '+' || *ptr == '-'){
        sign = *ptr;
        ++ptr;
    }
    while(isdigit(*ptr)){
        a = *ptr - '0';
    beforeDecimal = beforeDecimal * c + a;
    ++ptr;
    }
    if(*ptr == '.'){
        ++ptr;
        while(isdigit(*ptr)){
            a = *ptr - '0';
    afterDecimal = afterDecimal + a/pow(c, exp);
    ++exp;
    ++ptr;
        }
    }
    beforeDecimal += afterDecimal;
    if(beforeDecimal){
        if(sign && sign == '-')
            beforeDecimal = -beforeDecimal;
        return beforeDecimal;
    }
    
    return 0;    
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    //parse and store the expression for calculation
    char *exp = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (EXPL +1)); // 1 is for null terminator \0
    if(exp == NULL)
        exit(-1);
    
    int count = 1; //extra 1 will store \0
    int i = 1, j = 1;
    
    // check whether argument are supplied
    if(argc < 2)
        return 0;
    
    //calculate the total size of arguments
    while(j < argc){
        count += strlen(argv[j]);
        ++j;
    }
    char *temp = malloc(sizeof(char) * count);
    if(!temp) exit(-1);
       //copy all arguments to temp
       for(i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
           strcat(temp, argv[i]);
       //check if the expression contains whitespaces
       //first check if it contains multiline argument and make it single line
       //then remove whitespaces
       if(strstr(temp," ") || strstr(temp, "\n")){
           char *tmp = temp;
           char *init = temp;
           while(*temp != '\0'){
               //remove all the \n
               if(*temp != ' ' && *temp != '\n'){
                   *tmp = *temp;
                   ++tmp;
               }
               ++temp;
           }
           *tmp = '\0';
    temp = init;
       }
       // check if the expression is within the limit i.e EXPL
       if(count > EXPL){
           printf("Expression is too long;\nMax %d digits.\nGiven %d\n ", EXPL, count);
           return 1;
       }
       else
           strcpy(exp, temp);
       free(temp);
       
       if(!validate(exp)){
           free(exp);
           return 1;
       }
       //since the expression is ready to be evaluated, let's evaluate it to produce the result
       evaluate(exp);
       puts(exp);
       free(exp);
       return 0;
}
```

here is replace.c

```
#include"replace.h"

char *replace(char *str,char *substr,  char *seed, int recursive)
{
    char *firstPos = strstr(str, substr);
    if(!firstPos)
        return NULL;

    long size = 0;
    long  strS, substrS, seedS, occurance;
    strS = substrS = seedS = occurance = 0;
    //calculate length of substr, seed and str
    strS = strlen(str);
    substrS = strlen(substr);
    seedS = strlen(seed);

    //declare a __temp string variable
    char *__tmp = malloc(strS + 1);
    if(!__tmp){
        puts("memory allocation failed!");
        return NULL;
    }
    //calculate the size of string required to hold the replaced string and replace its occurence
    if(!recursive){
        size = strS + (seedS - substrS);
        __tmp = realloc(__tmp, size + 1);
        if(!__tmp)
            return NULL;
        //remove substr and store its index
        long ind = (long)(firstPos - str);
        strncpy(__tmp, str, ind);
        __tmp[ind] = '\0';
        strcat(__tmp, firstPos + substrS);
        if(!seedS)
            return __tmp;
        return insert(__tmp, seed, ind);
    }
        
    else if(recursive){
        //count the occurance of substr
        strcpy(__tmp, str);
        char* pos;
        while((pos = strstr(__tmp, substr))){
            size = strlen(__tmp) + (seedS - substrS);
            long ind = (long)(pos - __tmp);

            __tmp = realloc(__tmp, size + 1);
            char *__temp = malloc(size + 1);
            if(!__tmp || !__temp)
                return NULL;
            strcpy(__temp, __tmp);
            // printf(">%s\n",__tmp);
            strncpy(__tmp, __temp, ind);
            __tmp[ind] = '\0';
            // printf(">>%s\n",__tmp);
            strcat(__tmp, __temp + ind + substrS);
            // printf(">>>%s\n",__tmp);
            free(__temp);
            if(seedS){
                __temp = insert(__tmp, seed, ind);
                strcpy(__tmp, __temp);
                free(__temp);
            }   
        }
        return __tmp;
    }
    return NULL;
}

char *insert(char *str, char *sed, int index)
{
    int strl, sedl;
    strl = (int)strlen(str);
    sedl = (int)strlen(sed);
    char *dest = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (strl + sedl +1));
    if(dest == NULL) return NULL;
    
    strncpy(dest, str, index );
    dest[index] = '\0';
    strcat(dest, sed);
    strcat(dest, str + index);
    return dest;
}
```

and here is the test file
test.py

```
from ast import Return
import subprocess as sp


tests = ["243 + 45*3 -43 + 45/9 + 6^6",
        "34 + 23 -54 + '6(76(32(56 + 45 -34(56- 34)) + 44)) *' 45 -7 ^ 5 -  4",
        "43 + 3.543 - 543.36 - 56.84*23.456 + 18/5 - '45.465(56 + 45 -34(59- 24))63.86' + 34",
        "5 ^ 3.543 - 543.36 - 56.84*23.456 + 18/5 - '45.465(56 + 45 -34(65- 41))63.86' + 3.345 ^ 4.65 + 456 - 29/3 ^ 2.34 - 11/4 ^ 3",
        '''23 + 345- 240*4 + '6+ 4 * 4' - '(5-2) / (4+ (5-3))' *6 + "45 - 23 +24 * (3+(4+3))
        +987543-45345+8635
        6453354 --"''',
    '''23*240*4 *'6+ 4 * 4 - (5-2)  (4+ (5-3))'  "45345 - 8(4+3) + 3(5-2)6 - (7+5)4 - 6(5+3^2)9 (5  *  4 -6)5 ^7" - 6 + "45 - 23 +24 * (3+(4+3))(6)"''',
        " '54( 34 + 34 - 23 + 34/12 + 3 ^4)'",
        " '5+54+( 34 + 34 - 23 + 256/16^2*8 + 34) - 32'",
        " '69( 31 + 4 - 23 + 72/6^2*8 + 34) - 32'",
        " '5+54+ 34 + 34 - 23 + (8) - 32'"
        ]

com = sp.run("gcc  calc.c replace.c -o calc -lm", shell = True, capture_output = True, text = True)
if (com.returncode):
    print(com.stderr)
    exit(0)

print("~~~Compiled Successfully~~~")
for test in tests:
    ret = sp.run("./calc " + test,shell=True, capture_output = True, text = True)
    if(ret.stderr):
        print(ret.stderr)
    else:
        print(ret.stdout)
```

**Everything works fine, in the file replace.c, (tested it many time)
the error occurs in the function**

1. evaluate()
2. calculate() and
3. operate()
   **in the calc.c file.**

Comment: This question is better for https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: first things I notice is your temp buffer isn't big enough for null terminator. That could corrupt your heap

Comment: some other issues, but at the end of `validate`, you reallocate your src pointer, but you don't return the new pointer so `evaluate` is still using the released pointer